JavaFX: Plot points in a Javafx Application
I am developing a Javafx application where a user inputs coordinates and they get plotted to the side. Currently I've managed to make the input work, but I have no idea as to how to proceed to making the points plotted.
This is how the window looks. The points should be plotted to the right:

This is my FXML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox minHeight="600.0" minWidth="900.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.lovethefrogs.optigraph.controller.HomeController">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="564.0" prefWidth="900.0">
        <items>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="551.0" prefWidth="349.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <TextField fx:id="nameInput">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                     <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Coord X">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <TextField fx:id="xCoordInput">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                     <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Coord Y">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <TextField fx:id="yCoordInput">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <Button fx:id="addNodeButton" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAddNodeButtonClick" text="Add Node">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <ListView fx:id="nodeList" prefHeight="197.0" prefWidth="333.0">
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </ListView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="349.0">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Delete node">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <TextField fx:id="idInput" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="id of the node to delete">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <Button fx:id="deleteButton" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDeleteButtonClick" text="Delete">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>
        <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-1.0" text="OptiGraph" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <font>
            <Font size="11.0" fx:id="x3" />
          </font>
          <textFill>
            <Color red="0.625" green="0.625" blue="0.625" fx:id="x4" />
          </textFill>
        </Label>
        <Pane prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Label font="$x3" maxWidth="-1.0" text="By LovetheFrogs" textFill="$x4" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
      </children>
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
      </padding>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</VBox>

I have tried to use a chart, but it is not what I'm looking for. I have some logic in the background where all coordinates input by the user are saved, so they can all be ploted at once

Write a standalone application that defines a hardcoded array of points and plots them on a scene (doing nothing else), not using FXML at all.  Add the points (e.g. Circles) to an unmanaged layout pane (e.g. a Group or Pane) to display them.  Once that works, copy that logic into the rest of your application, with all the FXML and everything else you need.

A complete textbook example is cited here.

First, you need to understand how JavaFX plots in a Pane. Then, you need to create an X-axis and Y-axis and translate the X and Y coordinates to your new XY plane. Your other option is to use a chart.
